# Battery indicator not descending, sudden shut down

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

my problem is kind of simple, I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7.
When I use it with battery, the indicator of the battery level doesn't go down, it stays at 100% for about 3 hours (normal battery life) and then the laptop goes to hibernation mode without any warning whatsoever. Could someone tell me how can I fix this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution [here on Jeffrey Palermo’s blog](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2010/05/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/) may cure this. If, as I did, after trying this solution you just get the message "No battery is detected", try:

1. Shut down
2. Disconnect AC
3. Start up
4. Connect AC.

If still no joy, then the cause may be dirt on one of the terminals on the laptop that connect to the battery. This can be removed by rubbing the contacts with a thin piece of plastic dipped in vinegar. A few minutes at room temperature ought to suffice to ensure that all moisture has gone before powering up.